# Confidence intervals for odds ratio in GLMM with interactions

Tags: mixed-model, confidence-interval, glmm, odds-ratio

I have the following output from a GLMM

The model is 
$$
\log\left(\dfrac{p_{i}}{1 - p_{i}}\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \texttt{type}_i + \beta_2\texttt{treat}_i + \beta_3(\texttt{type}\times\texttt{treat})_i + \alpha_i 
$$
where $\texttt{type}$ can take on values DM1, DM2, or GODM; $\texttt{treat}$ can take on values standard or telcare; and $\alpha_i$ is a random intercept.

```
                             Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)                -0.7048315  0.5573133 -1.264695 0.2059805700
Diab.TypeDM2                0.9609791  0.7469077  1.286610 0.1982301487
Diab.TypeGODM               1.3646073  0.7671772  1.778738 0.0752827140
treattelcare               -3.6981407  1.0160925 -3.639571 0.0002730928
Diab.TypeDM2:treattelcare   2.3718270  1.2490692  1.898876 0.0575808341
Diab.TypeGODM:treattelcare  3.3297053  1.9572327  1.701231 0.0888995871
```

and confidence intervals:

```
                                 2.5 %     97.5 %
.sig01                      1.21377397  2.0816752
(Intercept)                -1.82918259  0.4227302
Diab.TypeDM2               -0.56565520  2.4505108
Diab.TypeGODM              -0.18181760  2.9166684
treattelcare               -5.87668163 -1.7752781
Diab.TypeDM2:treattelcare  -0.03011557  5.0136622
Diab.TypeGODM:treattelcare -0.52476249  7.4012963
```

**I want to give the odds ratio estimates (and confidence intervals) would this be correct:**

odds ratio for DM1 (telcare vs standard):

`exp(-3.6981407)`
CI:

`exp(c(-5.87668163, -1.7752781))`

odds ratio for DM2 (telcare vs standard):

`exp(-3.6981407 + 2.3718270)`

CI:

`exp(c(-5.87668163, -1.7752781) + c(-0.03011557,  5.0136622))`

odds ratio for GODM (telcare vs standard):

`exp(-3.6981407 + 3.3297053)`

CI:

`exp(c(-5.87668163, -1.7752781) + c(-0.52476249, 7.4012963))`